# Python3 or C/C++: TWAIN interface

Tags: c++, c, python-3.x, twain

I have seen twain module for Python2, is there anything similar for Python3?
I need to control scanning process and, specifically, histogram settings (shadow, highlight, gamma), resolution and scanning window size. What would be the best way to automate it in Python3?

**EDIT:** If not in Python, are there any C/C++ libraries which could be integrated into Python and control scanning process? I know only one library, EZTwain, it supports multiple programming languages (*excluding* Python) but it didn't work for some histogram settings and there was no support even for commercial version, so I would avoid using it.

Comment: There are plenty of scanner software that can do this already, so to answer that we would have to know *why* you need to do this, and why you are limiting yourself to TWAIN (which is a standard in practice only used on Windows afaik).

Comment: There is a Python3 GUI which makes calculations out the images taken from the scanner, one image is made with three different settings which would mean manual setting them, three more scan buttton pushes and one more GUI interface. Also, Epson scan does not allow to save settings and send them to other user which complicates the process of installing the system for end user. I know, some other commercial programms do that, but again, I want to keep just one GUI. For the future project scaning settings will be changed depending on some Python GUI settings and user doen't have to care about it.

Comment: Why TWAIN? I don't know any other on Windows...

Comment: Well, no other has Python support anyway, so updating the Python 2 module so it works on Python 3 seems the best option in this case.

Comment: I tried 2to3 update with some other modules and it always was waste of time and didn't work at the end... I think only module developer or active contributor could do such job. Is there maybe any way to use C/C++ library with TWAIN support and integrate it into Python3?

Comment: Very few modules work after just running 2to3 on the, 2to3 only does the boring bits, the rest is up to you. Anyone can do it, that's what open source is about. Obviously it would necessitate you learning the innards of the code, and if you did it you would *be* an active contributor. :-)

Comment: Personally I am not familiar with Python. But I think Dynamic Web TWAIN (ActiveX Edition) might work for you. This edition is developed with pure Win32 API and assembly language. Check it out: http://www.dynamsoft.com/Products/WebTWAIN_Features.aspx

Comment: Never saw it, thank you, I'll have to check its functionality and the license cost - there are too many options... And what about DTwain library (http://www.dynarithmic.com/details_dtwain.html), any experience with it?

Answer (score 2):

We use a third-party toolkit named leadtools that might help you. This toolkit supports the most common programming languages including C/C++, C#, VB.NET and so more. For more information, you can check these 2 help topics:

For .NET:
[Acquiring an Image using .NET](http://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v175/dh/to/leadtools.topics.twain~tw.topics.twainacquiringanimage.html)

For C++:
[Acquiring an Image using C++](http://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v175/twain/clib/dlltutor/twainimplement.htm)